# Remove ID from Dom if empty in Oxygen Builder

Tags: jquery, wordpress

This is a development question, and any help is much appreciated. Here goes...

I know it's possible to remove all the ID's in Oxygen with this js input;

```
jQuery('body:not(.oxygen-builder-body) *').removeAttr('id');
```

But is it possible to change this so that all ID's will be removed except for all the ID's with a prefix For example: id="prefix-idname".

Example id in Oxygen builder below. I can remove this, but the result is that the ID is still in the Dom. See below.

[image: id still in dom even when removed]

As you can see below in the source code, the ID is empty but the prefix is still there in the Dom. I want this to be removed, keeping the class only.

[image: id is not removed from dom]

The final output would be: **<section class="ct-section-slider"....</section>.**.

This process needs to be revered as well. So If the ID starts with a prefix-idname in Oxygen Builders id field, the ID will not be removed. This needs to apply to all nested div's that might be under the main div .

The final output would be: **<section id="section-2-5" class="ct-section-slider"....</section>.**.

Why do I want this? I just want a clean HTML source, because usually we get empty ID's and don't use them in Oxygen Builder.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve the problem.

1. I use JavaScript to find the ids that are empty and delete them. If you feel like manually 'cleaning' all the ids within the builder use this:

a. I select elements with an id

b. Uses a `forEach` loop to check whether each element has an empty ID attribute. If it is empty, the `removeAttribute` function is used to remove it.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll("[id]");
    
elements.forEach(el => {
  if (el.getAttribute("id") === "") {
    el.removeAttribute("id");
  }
});
```

2. If you only want to remove the 'id' attribute from an element with a specific class, e.g. `removeId`, use the more specific CSS selector

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".removeId[id]");
        
elements.forEach(el => {
  el.removeAttribute("id");
});
```

Hope this help :)